# How to get business weekly averages per method in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following problem. Suppose I have a wide data Frame consisting of three columns (mock example follows below). Essentially, it consists of three factors, `A`, `B` and `C` for which I have certain values for each business day within a time range.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index_d = pd.bdate_range(start='10/5/2022', end='10/27/2022')
index = np.repeat(index_d,3)
values = np.random.randn(3*len(index_d), 1)
columns_v = len(index_d)*["A","B","C"]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["x"] = np.asarray(index)
df["y"] = values
df["factor"] = np.asarray([columns_v]).T
```

I would like to plot the business weekly averages of the the three factors along time. A business week goes from Monday to Friday. However, in the example above I start within a week and end within a week. That means the first weekly averages consist only of the data points on 5th, 6th and 7th of October. Similar for the last week. Ideally, the output should have the form

```
dt1 = dt.datetime.strptime("20221007", "%Y%m%d").date()
dt2 = dt.datetime.strptime("20221014", "%Y%m%d").date()
dt3 = dt.datetime.strptime("20221021", "%Y%m%d").date()
dt4 = dt.datetime.strptime("20221027", "%Y%m%d").date()

d = 3*[dt1, dt2, dt3, dt4]
values = np.random.randn(len(d), 1)
factors = 4*["A","B","C"]
df_output = pd.DataFrame()
df_output["time"] = d
df_output["values"] = values
df_output["factors"] = factors
```

I can then plot the weekly averages using seaborn as a lineplot with `hue`. Important to note is that the respective time value for weekly average is always the last business day in that week (Friday except for the last, where it is a Thursday).

I was thinking of groupby. However, given that my real data is much larger and has possibly some `NaN` I'm not sure how to do it. In particular with regards to the random start / end points that don't need to be Monday / Friday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
res = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='x', freq='W-FRI'),df.factor])['y'].mean()\
    .reset_index(drop=False)

res = res.rename(columns={'x':'time','factor':'factors','y':'values'})

res['time'] = res.time.map(pd.merge_asof(df.x, res.time, left_on='x', 
                                         right_on='time', direction='forward')\
                           .groupby('time').last()['x']).astype(str)

print(res)

          time factors    values
0   2022-10-07       A  0.171228
1   2022-10-07       B -0.250432
2   2022-10-07       C -0.126960
3   2022-10-14       A  0.455972
4   2022-10-14       B  0.582900
5   2022-10-14       C  0.104652
6   2022-10-21       A -0.526221
7   2022-10-21       B  0.371007
8   2022-10-21       C  0.012099
9   2022-10-27       A -0.123510
10  2022-10-27       B -0.566441
11  2022-10-27       C -0.652455
```

Plot data:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
ax = sns.lineplot(data=res, x='time', y='values', hue='factors')
sns.move_legend(ax, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image: lineplots]

---

**Explanation**

- First, apply [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Grouping by `factor` is of course easy; for the dates we can use [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with `freq` parameter set to `W-FRI` (each week through to *Friday*), and then we want to get the `mean` for column `y` (`NaN` values will just be ignored).
- In the next step, let's use [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to rename the columns.
- We are basically done now, except for the fact that `pd.Grouper` will use each *Friday* (even if it isn't present in the actual set). E.g.:

```
print(res.time.unique())

['2022-10-07T00:00:00.000000000' '2022-10-14T00:00:00.000000000'
 '2022-10-21T00:00:00.000000000' '2022-10-28T00:00:00.000000000']
```

- If you are OK with this, you can just start plotting (but see below). If you would like to get `'2022-10-27'` instead of `'2022-10-28'`, we can combine [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) applied to column `time` with [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html),and perform another `groupby` to get `last` in column `x`. I.e. this will get us the closest match to each Friday within each week (so, in fact just Friday in *all* cases, except the last: `2022-10-17`).
- In either scenario, before plotting, make sure to turn the datetime values into strings: `res['time'] = res['time'].astype(str)`!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column with the calendar week:

```
df['week'] = df.x.dt.isocalendar().week
```

Get a mask for all the Fridays, and for the last day:

```
last_of_week = (df.x.dt.isocalendar().day == 5).values
last_of_week[-1] = True
```

Get the actual dates:

```
last_days = df.x[last_of_week].unique()
```

Group by `week` and `factor`, take the mean:

```
res = df.groupby(['week', 'factor']).mean().reset_index()
```

Clean up:

```
res = res.drop('week', axis=1)
res['x'] = pd.Series(last_days).repeat(3).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This will only lead to the desired output as long as there are no repeated weeks. E.g. suppose the OP is working with `pd.bdate_range(start='1/1/2020', end='12/31/2022')`, then your `res` will end up having `159` rows instead the `471` that are actually needed. E.g. in such a case, you will be counting `week 1` *for each of the three years* as just `week 1`. This is clearly not what the OP wants. One might think that you could add the `year` as well to get the correct `groupby`, but that's not true, because `week 1` of the isocalendar does not necessarily start in the new year.